# How do I simplify general WPF render to maximize performance?

Tags: wpf, performance, optimization

I have to use self-written WPF application via Remote Desktop with slow Internet connection.

When it comes to scrolling - it looks like application hangs for a second or two. Application runs pretty fast on local computer but when it comes to RDP performance become dissapointment.

I guess I have to simplify WPF render as much as possible. I'd like somehow to tell WPF subsystem: render all of your controls as simple as you can.

What would you suggest here?

Comment: It's a third party component (Avalon Editor). I guess it's a kind of ListView

Answer (score 2):

There are some tips from the [Visual Studio team](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/02/wpf-in-visual-studio-2010-part-2-performance-tuning.aspx) relating to RDP. [This post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2010/02/27/optimizing-visual-studio-2010-and-wpf-applications-for-remote-desktop.aspx) has a lot of details such as reducing the framerate and implementing [VisualScrollableAreaClip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.visualscrollableareaclip.aspx). I had a quick look and AvalonEdit doesn't seem to use VisualScrollableAreaClip so that and the other settings mentioned in that post might be worth looking into before retemplating all your controls.